# WrapText using alasql

Tags: javascript, angularjs, alasql

how can i extract spreadsheet with a  wraptext using alasql, this is what i thought will work :

```
var mystyle = {
    headers: true,
    columns: [{
        columnid: 'Description',
        width: 50,
        wraptext: true
    }],
    rows: {
        1: {
            style: {
                Font: {
                    Color: "#FF0077"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    cells: {
        1: {
            1: {
                style: {
                    Font: {
                        Color: "#00FFFF"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
$scope.exportMyData = function() {
    alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSXML("john.xls",?) FROM ?', [mystyle, $scope.gridOptions.data]);
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?